# Getting data from component VueJS

Tags: vue.js, components

Very simple question. I'm learning VueJS and have created a simple component:

```
Vue.component('blog-post', {
    props: ['title'],
    template: '<h3>{{ title }}</h3>'
})
```

I then have parsed some data to it like this:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#blog-post-demo',
    data: {
        posts: [
            { id: 1, title: 'My journey with Vue' },
            { id: 2, title: 'Blogging with Vue' },
            { id: 3, title: 'Why Vue is so fun' }
        ]
    }
})
```

My question is how can get the title of a specefic element based on the id in my HTML? For now I can only render through the items and get them all, but I want to be able to specify which title I want to display based on the Id. Here is my HTML which gives me all the data:

```
<div id="blog-post-demo">
    <blog-post
           v-for="post in posts"
           v-bind:key="post.id"
           v-bind:title="post.title"
   ></blog-post>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly what you want to do. But if you want to go through all posts and display title of particular post then you can try this way:

```
   <blog-post
       v-for="post in posts"
       :key="post.id"
       :title="setTitle(post)"
   />
```

(`:` instead of `:v-bind` it's a [short form](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Shorthands), also if you don't pass slots in your component you can go with [self-closing](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Self-closing-components-strongly-recommended) tag)

Then in your `methods` section you can create a method:

```
setTitle(post) {
 if(post.id === 2) return post.title
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve with COMPUTED property, like that

```
<template>
<div id="blog-post-demo">
    <p v-for="post in thisOne" :key="post.id" >
      {{post.title}}
   </p>
</div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  el: '#blog-post-demo',
    data() {
      return {
        posts: [
            { id: 1, title: 'My journey with Vue' },
            { id: 2, title: 'Blogging with Vue' },
            { id: 3, title: 'Why Vue is so fun' }
        ]
        }
    },computed: {
      thisOne(){
        return this.posts.filter(x => x.id === 3); /*choose your id*/
      }
    }
};
</script>
```

Or you can use event too to select the id of the posts to display (more dynamically)

Tip: If you start with VueJS, learn about the properties of VueJs (DATA, COMPUTED, CREATED, METHOD) and look at the uses and strengths of each one. For my part, the VueJS site is very very well done for beginners: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/